# How to yank or delete multiple lines in Vim, all in different ranges?

Tags: vim

I've seen a couple of questions about yanking and deleting a range of lines in Vim, for example, from line 5 to line 10.

However, I haven't found (in documentation and googling) about how to yank/delete in a single command, for example, lines 3, 5, 10 and 12.

Is this possible?

Comment: This has been asked and answered on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608204/multiple-selections-in-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it's not simple. Vim does not support multiple ranges or multiple, non-adjacent line numbers. See

```
:help 10.3
:help :range
```

You could specify the lines to be yanked in the pattern of a `:g` command, though, using the line number atom. See

```
:help :g
:help /\%l
```

In the case of your example, the following would yank those lines into the `a` register.

```
:g/\%3l\|\%5l\|\%10l\|\%12l/y A
```

Comment: Note, for this to work as intended, the 'a' register must be empty. An easy way to do this, is to record an empty macro, by pressing `qaq` in normal mode.